# What's the best style in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Made serious progress also thanks to Erik Meijer's lectures. Good watch, maybe a hint. Haskell allows for several ways to write the same function. Which one of these would be best in terms of efficiency and readability?

```
sqr' = \x -> x * x
sqr'' x = x * x
sqr''' = (^2)
```

Comment: You forgot `sqr'''' = join (*)` as a fourth option :) The first two should be equivalent (ignoring type inference issues), as the second is syntactic sugar for the first. I'm not sure if there would be any difference between the first two and the third (although you could also consider `sqr = join (*)` as a point-free equivalent to the first two).

Comment: I think most people would consider `sqr''` as the most readable, and the performance issues between any of the three should be negligible.

Comment: There's probably a dozen minor variations on how to write this. It is *highly unlikely* that there's any performance difference at all (unless the types end up being different). Which one is *most readable* depends on who you ask.

Comment: @AdamSmith WHNF is not really related to this (WHNF is not generally used in the context of describing written code directly, since it is about evaluation order. If anything, though, all of the options would be in WHNF since they are all function values). Maybe you mean point-free?

Comment: @DavidYoung sorry, yes, point-free!

Answer (score 3):

Between these two top-level definitions:

```
sqr' = \x -> x * x
sqr'' x = x * x
```

the second is pretty much universally preferred in Haskell programs.  Search through almost any chunk of real-world Haskell code, and you will find many examples of the second but few of the first. Instead, "lambda abstraction" (i.e., the `\x -> ...` syntax) is most often used for defining anonymous functions to pass as arguments to higher order functions.

There are a couple of reasons the second syntax is preferred.  First, it's literally more concise and, from a readability perspective, incorporates fewer distinct syntactic elements (i.e., juxtaposition and the `=` operator, instead of juxtaposition, `=`, `\`, and `->`).  It also generalizes well to the common Haskell idiom of defining a function using multiple patterns:

```
factorial 0 = 1
factorial n | n > 0 = n * factorial (n-1)
```

To do this with the lambda syntax, you'd need to add an explicit `case` construct, involving *yet another* set of syntactic elements.

Between:

```
sqr'' x = x * x
sqr''' = (^2)
```

or -- perhaps a fairer comparison -- between:

```
sqr'''' x = x^2
sqr''' = (^2)
```

it's more a matter of personal preference.  Many Haskell programmers like the clean look of so-called [point-free](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree) syntax, where larger functions are made up using higher-order functions and/or chains of composed functions without explicit arguments, like:

```
mostFrequentWord
   = head . maximumBy (comparing length) . group . sort . words
```

and definitions like `sqr'''` are more in line with this overall style.

In terms of differences in *meaning* between these forms, it's actually a little complicated.  For obscure reasons having to do with things called "the monomorphism restriction" and "defaulting rules", if you took the following module:

```
module Square where
sqr' = \x -> x * x
sqr'' x = x * x
sqr''' = (^2)
```

and compiled it with `ghc -O`, the definitions of `sqr'` and `sqr'''` would be equivalent -- both would be specialized to operate on the `Integer` type and would generate exactly the same code.  (Tested with GHC 8.0.2).  In contrast, `sqr''` remains polymorphic with signature `Num a => a -> a`, meaning it can operate on any numeric type.

If you add top-level type signatures (good practice anyway!), like so:

```
module Square where
sqr', sqr'', sqr''' :: (Num a) => a -> a
sqr' = \x -> x * x
sqr'' x = x * x
sqr''' = (^2)
```

then they all generate exactly the same code.  You can verify this yourself by peeking at the generated "core" (the intermediate Haskell-like language that the compiler creates as a midpoint in the compilation process) using:

```
ghc -O -ddump-simpl -dsuppress-all -fforce-recomp Square.hs
```

In the generated core, you'll see the definition:

```
sqr' = \ @ a_aBC $dNum_aLW x_arx -> * $dNum_aLW x_arx x_arx
```

which looks weird, but basically says, apply the `*` operation for the appropriate `Num` type to the arguments `x_arx x_arx`.  The generated code for the two variants:

```
sqr'' = sqr'
sqr''' = sqr'
```

shows that GHC sees no difference between them and `sqr'`, and so there will be no semantic or performance difference.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the elaborate explanations to all of you. This already provides me with a load of new insights. Really appreciate the time you take to answer my (sometimes absurd) questions. But it does help me along much quicker!